# How to combine the totals of four sheets into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to combine the totals of four sheets into one.

I am creating a spreadsheet to keep track of the hours spent each day working on different project (M-F).

[image]

I have five days of data. They all have the same layout.

At the end of the week, I want to add up each row's sum for m-f and put in a separate sheet called end of week total so I can see how many hours each week we spent on a project. I am basically creating a spreadsheet for each day of the week that shows how many hours my employees worked on each project. At the end of the week I want all of the hours to add up, but only for each a specific row. not the total number of hours.

[image]

I have no idea how to combine sheets.

Comment: You can refer to other sheets when building a formula. When you've begun entering the formula on Sheet 5 and are at the point where you'd enter the cell address(es) you're summing, just flip over to the worksheet and cells you're trying to sum and select the cells as you normally would.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Oju3e

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/nqBsL

Comment: I have five days of data. They all have the same layout.

Comment: I want to add up each row's sum for m-f and put in a separate sheet called end of week total.

Comment: I am basically creating a spreadsheet for each day of the week that shows how many hours my employees worked on each project. At the end of the week I want all of the hours to add up but only for each specific row. not the total number of hours... if this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The formula in sheet5 should look like this:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1,Sheet4!A1)
```

Replacing A1 with the column and row of the totals in sheets 1 through 4.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own.

Here is the link if anyone else needs help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRtgIfIfAHE